# Flutter Firebase permission-denied

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm got an error when try to set data to Firestore Firebase

```
FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.)
```

Firestore Firebase rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

My try

```
 await usersCollection.doc(cred.user!.uid).set({
      "email": email,
      "name": name,
      "password": password,
      "createdate": DateTime.now().toString(),
    });
```

Comment: r u using Firebase-Authentication? if so then try this *(allow read, create, write: if request.auth != null;).  if u don' then *(allow read, write: true;)

Comment: @JBJason I'm using Firebase Authentication

Comment: I'm added, still got an error

`rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, create, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: How do you define `usersCollection`? Note that the `{document=**}` path matches any document in the entire database. You should change that in Production environment and declare specific rules for each collection.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the collection name is missing here

try

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /collectionName/{document=**} {
```

Comment: still same error as above

Comment: try step debugging
1. Hope you have added the init code
 await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
verify if your firebase has been initialised properly. You could check this the console.log